# How to handle quick incoming network packages ?

Tags: c#

On my application i receiving UDP packages and i need to analyze them. 
When package1 get to my machine - i must lock some scope and make the analyzing before analyzing package2.

The network get package all the time and there is a possible case the while i analyzing package1 ... the network layer got package2 and package3 and they are waiting for analyzing.

I can add any package to concurrentQueue - but i afraid that adding to this queue is using lock and while the queue is locked and two package2 and package3 are received and are on waiting ... and the lock is release .. then there is possible case that package3 will be added before package2 ... and then package3 will be analyze before package2 and this is a bug.

someone have other solution ?

Comment: Result of analyzing `package1` will affect analyzing `package2` ? If no, why you just not create `threads` for analyzing each package separately ?

Comment: yes, this will effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ConcurrentQueue` is a lock-free thread-safe implementation of the standard queue data structure. It means that Adding/Removing from queue will not lock it.

And if you call `Enqueue` it will add item to queue **for sure**. ( This method hasn't return value and hasn't any throwing exceptions ).

It means in the `ConcurrentQueue` items will be in the same sequence in which  the `Enqueue` method has been called.

Example, how Enqueue can be implemented:

```
public void Enqueue(T item) {
    int insertIndex = Interlocked.Increment(ref m_high);
    m_array[insertIndex] = item;
}
```

Note: If you get `package1` and `package2` in same time with different threads, it mean that in any case architecture of program is broken. If `package1` and `package2` are logicaly nested, how `client` can sent them in same time. If somehow client sent them in same time, you can't handle it.

Comment: ok , so let say in my application i listen to too port ... port 1 and port 2 :: now, i adding the information from port 1 to this queue and also adding information from port 2 to the same queue ==> now, port 1 and port 2 are sending to me on the same time --- is after the adding of those both ports the queue will hold the right information ?

if it is so how come its done without lock ?

Comment: @Yanshof Please see my updated answer. Also if you are adding information from port1 and port2 in same time, what you mean by saying `the queue will hold the right information`, if the packages comes in same time, how you can determinate what package is first what is second (what is right order?). Client should send information in right order, if so, you will handle it.